# Munit 2.2.1 not working in Mule runtime 4.3.0

Tags: mule-component, mulesoft, mule4

I upgraded mule runtime from 4.2.2 to 4.3.0
I installed mule 4.3.0 in anypoint studio 7.4.2 and changed mule-artifact.json to 4.3.0 and in pom file i changed some connector to latest version and mule maven plugin to 3.5.1
Code is getting deployed successfully but munit is failing
Could you please suggest a solution

Comment: Failing how? Please show the errors and symptoms. Have you already tried using the last version of MUnit (2.3.2) and Studio 7.8.0?

Answer (score 1):

MUnits will not work the same way in runtime 4.3.0 unless you upgrade Munit dependent artifacts in your project's pom.xml file

The following artifacts need to be updated to latest versions

```
<artifactId>munit-tools</artifactId>  to say 2.3.1
<artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId> to say 2.3.1
<munit.version> to minimum 2.2.1
```

Also make sure you are using the correct version of the APIKit Router.

Few other observations we noticed when migrating to 4.3 was in some places String "true" was equal to boolean true in runtime 4.2.0 but not same in 4.3.

Please share your final resolution.

Regards
Mahesh Raja Vandyala